# How to connect using java to DB2 database with TLS version 1.2?

Tags: ssl, db2, tls1.2

I see we have different parameters for connecting to the DB2 database like,

```
sslConnection=true
sslTrustStoreLocation=/opt/db211.5/sslkey_b2biqarhlmk9/key.jks
sslTrustStorePassword=password
```

This parameter can be passed to the JDBC url for DB2, and this establishes the SSL connection between application and DB2 database.
However, is there a way by which we can restrict the TLS version for the connection? How to specify the exact TLS version, say TLSv1.2 for this connection?

Thanks
Dev

Comment: This is decided in part by the Db2-server configuration. When asking for help with Db2, please always specify in your question what is the Db2-server platform (z/os, i series(as400), linux/unix/windows/cloud), because this determines the answer often. For example with Db2-LUW, the __server__ instance configuration __SSL_VERSIONS__ can be set to TLSV12 only.

Comment: Thanks @mao , So from the client side we dont have any such parameter, so implicitly it would support tls 1.0/1.1/1.2 ? And ofcourse driver has to facilitate it.
This obligation is on the server, how it configures itself to different tls versions?

Comment: Please answer the clarification, what is your Db2-server and platform, by editing your question.

Comment: Sure, I am checking with the team. I will get back with the info in sometime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `sslVersion=TLSv1.2;` property to your URL.
This prevents connections to non-TLSv12 enabled Db2 LUW databases or enforce TLSv1.2 mode if, say, your server supports both modes with `SSL_VERSIONS` dbm cfg set to `TLSV12,TLSV1`.